# AspNet mudar características do textBox dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Para teste criei um botão o qual chama uma função em javascript através do onclick(). Nessa função gostaria de mudar por exemplo a cor da borda do textBox, melhor ainda seria mudar a cor daquela borda azul padrão que tem quando o textBox está selecionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar estilos dinamicamente para mudar as características do seu textbox. Exemplo:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 //Você pode usar classe
<style type="text/css">
    .borda {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function mudarEstilo() {

        //exemplo sem usar classe, aqui eu adiciono uma borda de 1px de largura do formato solid e vermelha diretamente na propriedade css do input
        $('#txtTeste').css("border", "1px solid red"); 

        //aqui eu uso uma classe para o input, essa classe também tem borda de 1px de largura forma
        //prefiro essa solução
        $('#txtTeste').addClass("borda"); 
    }
</script>
</head>
 <body>
   <input type="button" value="Teste" onclick="mudarEstilo();" /> 
   <input type="text" id="txtTeste" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: obrigado, deu certo. Eu havia tentado de forma parecida, não lembro direito do motivo de não ter dado certo. Você tem um site que tenha todas essas propriedades .css que o jquery usa?

Comment: na verdade, o que eu realmente queria mudar era a cor do textBox, cor azul padrão, de quando ele está selecionado. Você sabe como fazer isso? Eu andei vendo algo sobre pegar o elemento e usar alguma propriedade do mesmo para modificar algo, não consegui entender muito bem como faz isso ainda. Ah, e o textBox é em asp.

Comment: @HeyJoe site do jquery : http://jquery.com/download/  eu baixei o 2.2.3.
O css é nativo não usei nem um framework. Abraços

Comment: @HeyJoe Você pode mudar a cor do textbox quando está selecionado sem precisar usar javascript. No seguinte exemplo o css só será aplicado quando o campo tiver foco, estou pintando a borda do campo de vermelho e colocando uma sombra de azul:
 #txtTeste:focus {
            border-color: red;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px blue;
        }